# How can I change non-numerical data to numerical values by using "if condition"?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change non-numerical data to numerical values in one column. I tried to use factorize; `pd.factorize(df['Class'])[0] + 1`. However, it separates the 'Class' column from the actual matrix (y1 matrix). Then, I also used `pd.get_dummies()`. But, it gave only 1 and 0 value for each different non-numerical value.

My question is, is there any way to change non-numerical data to numerical values starting from 1 to 4 in my case, for the data in one column? or any other suggestions that you would like to give.

In the 'Class' data, I have one column. 356 rows. The cells contain N, O, P and S letters.

Thank you very much for any help.

```
def my_function(y1):
    if y1 == "N":
        convert = 1,
    elif y1 == "A":
            convert = 2,
        elif y1 == "O":
                convert = 3,
                else:  
                    convert = 4
    return convert
```

Comment: Is `df["Class"] = pd.factorize(df["Class"])[0] + 1` not working? Do you want a specific mapping instead of this i.e., `N` must be 1 and so on?

Comment: It is working. However, it separates the column from the actual matrix. What I want, is not to change its actual matrix, (its actual location from the dataset). Also, yes, I tried to convert the data from 1 to 4 for each letter. But, it could not work out. Any help would be great...

Comment: So you'd like to have another column i.e., `df["New Class"] = pd.factorize(df["Class"])[0] + 1`? I'm not sure what you mean by *actual matrix* but maybe someone else will...

Comment: The actual matrix here, is a data frame in Spyder (Python 3.8). The data frame consists of 1 column and 356 rows.  In each rows, it contains different letters. (N, A, O and P)

Comment: Okay, so with `map` we can do `df["Numbered Class"] = df["Class"].map({"N": 1, "A": 2, "O": 3, "P": 4})` and I believe this doesn't separate the column from the actual matrix, right?

Comment: @vdu16 Have you tried LabelEncoder?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thank you very much Mustafa. (pd.factorize) function actually worked again. I was missing some parts to make it more correct. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following can be easily extended by changing the dict A.
I've defined A outside of the function `my_function()` to prevent a static array to be created over and over again.

```
A = { 'N' : 1, 'A' : 2, 'O' : 3 }

def my_function(y1):
    global A
    if (y1 in A):
        return A[y1]
    return 4

print(str(my_function('N')))
print(str(my_function('X')))
print(str(my_function('A')))
```

But maybe I'm missing the question all together.
It works both for Python2 and Python3

Comment: Thank you very much. That could work as well. However, there was a data frame, which should have been taken care of, in my case. I realized the actual problem and being solved! :) Thankful for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Label Encoding,

So,

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["N", "O", "P", "S"])
>>> LabelEncoder()

le.transform(["N", "N", "P", "O", "S", "O"]) + 1
>>> array([1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2])
```

For a column in a dataframe,

```
df['Class'] = le.fit_transform(df['Class']) + 1
```

Note, fit_transform is used for fitting and transform at the same time, if the data can have missing classes, then a separate fit is required specifying the actual classes.

Comment: Yes, I tried LabelEncoder at first, but, it led to order the numbers from 2. In the beginning, I couldn't handle that the first starting number would be from 1 in my case. and now, using (pd.factorize), it helped me again :) In any case, I am so thankful for your valuable help.

Comment: @vdu16 Glad, I could help, Can you please accept the answer and upvote this if possible.